# Let $ < S, +, · > $ be a subspace of $ < ℝ ^ 2, +, · > $ and let $ v ∈ S $ such that $ v ≠ 0 $, then, for every $ λ|λ∈ℝ $ it is true that $ λ·v ∈ S $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $ < S, +, · > $ be a subspace of $ < ℝ ^ 2, +, · > $ and let $ v ∈
> S $ such that $ v ≠ 0 $, then, for every $ λ|λ∈ℝ $ it is true that $
> λ·v ∈ S $

I have almost completed the proof, but I'm stuck in, what I suppose is, the final part.

From the hypothesis we know $ < S, +, · > $ is a subspace of $ < ℝ ^ 2, +, · > $, which is an $ℝ$-vector space, so we have $S ⊆ ℝ ^ 2$, $ S ≠ ∅ $ and $ < S, +, · > $ an $ℝ$-vector space.

Suppose $ v = ( a, b ) | a, b ≠ 0 $ and $ λ∈ℝ $, then, since $·$ is defined as

$$ ·: ℝ×ℝ ^ 2 ↦ ℝ ^ 2 $$
$$ [λ, ( a, b )] ↦ λ·(a,b) = (λa, λb) $$

---

*This is where doubts begin to arise; according to the definition of subspace, if S is a subspace of K, then S has the same operations as K, but I don't know if that includes the sets on which this operations are defined; I'll explain further: in this case $·$ is defined in $ℝ ^ 2$ as I just mentioned:
$$ ·: ℝ×ℝ ^ 2 ↦ ℝ ^ 2 $$
$$ [λ, ( a, b )] ↦ λ·(a,b) = (λa, λb) $$
does that mean that it is defined exactly like that for S, or the sets over which it is defined change like this? :
$$ ·: S×S ^ 2 ↦ S ^ 2 $$
$$ [λ, ( a, b )] ↦ λ·(a,b) = (λa, λb) $$
I assumed it stayed like 
$$ ·: ℝ×ℝ ^ 2 ↦ ℝ ^ 2 $$
$$ [λ, ( a, b )] ↦ λ·(a,b) = (λa, λb) $$
and followed the proof ( however, I need to confirm if this is correct ).*

---

then $ λ·v = λ·(a,b) = (λa,λb) $ and, because ℝ is closed under multiplication, then $λa,λb ∈ ℝ $ and $(λa,λb) ∈ ℝ^2 $, which is the same as $ λ·(a,b) ∈ ℝ^2 $ or $ λ·v ∈ ℝ^2 $

Here's where I get completely stuck, I already proved $λ·v ∈ ℝ^2$ but I still have to prove $λ·v ∈ S$, and I haven't figured out how to do so.

Any recommendation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that just the definition of subspace? I don't understand the question

Comment: I am also unclear as to why we wanted $v\neq 0$. It is certainly true in that case as well.

Comment: It's just my book that is asking me to prove this. It also says that if those elements of the form $λ·v$ are all the members of S, then the vector space S is graphically a line that passes through (0, 0).

Comment: @DanielBonillaJaramillo I don't think your book is asking you to prove this. The **definition** of a subspace is that it is closed under scalar multiplication. You can't prove a definition. Please verify that you copied the question prompt exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ means that if $x_1,x_2\in S$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\lambda_1\cdot x_1+\lambda_2\cdot x_2\in S$.

Thus if $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in S$ it follows that $(-\lambda)\cdot v+\lambda\cdot v=0\in S$ and therefore $\lambda\cdot 0+\lambda\cdot v=\lambda\cdot v\in S$

Note: In this context, of course, $0$ is $(0,0)$.

ADDENDUM: My answer above and OP's approach are both examples of "overthinking a problem."

Since $0,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in S$ it follows that $0\cdot v+\lambda\cdot v=\lambda\cdot v\in S$.